# How to set buttons position?

Tags: xcode, ipad

I'm working on an iPad application. On the main screen there are 6 buttons which was created in IB. I'd like to arrange them dynamically from code, but I can't.
Already tried setting the frame/center of the objects, but they didn't move.

I have an array which holds the button outlets, and arrange them in a for loop.
Is there any suggestion?

thanks!

edit:

Here's some code(not the whole, but the rest is irrelevant now), how I loop through the buttons. Button outlets already set properly. The title of the buttons changes properly, also I can hide/show the buttons, but not the position.

If I'll just try some dummy code like: 
`tempBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 200.0, 60.0, 40.0);`
nothing changes(but I suspect all the 6 buttons should be at the same position)

```
// I have this array, which contains the button outlets

tAddBtnArray = [NSArray ArrayWithObjects:tAddBtn1,tAddBtn2,tAddBtn3,tAddBtn4,tAddBtn5,tAddBtn6, nil];

//I loop through the array, set button title, and trying to change the y position
 for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        UIButton *tempBtn = [tAddBtnArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [tempField setText:@"Set some title"];
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the code you're using? Have you mapped the outlets to the buttons in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yup, I edited the original question with some code. Everything looks like working, as I wrote(can set almost everything on the buttton)

Comment: Can you tell me where this code is being run? What method call?

Comment: Now, it's in the viewDidAppear method. Already tried in the viewdidLoad and viewWillAppear, but hte result is the same in every case. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet I know what it is. Do you have autolayout enabled on the xib file? If so, the frame is being set, and then the constraints are being evaluated, which move the buttons back to where they were assigned.

You have two options:

1. Turn off autolayout, so that you can manage the frames yourself.
2. Leave autolayout on, but update the constraints as well as the frame.

I would suggest turning autolayout off, but I'm just not particularly fond of it, so it is just a preference.

Comment: Thanks Mate! I totally missed that could be cause this. I turned it off, now everything ok.

Comment: Yeah, I've had loads of issues with autolayout messing things up. Easiest way to see it is to do an animation and then the views jump back to where they were before the animation.

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would prefer either the old springs/struts or manual layout to autolayout, but even if you don't like it you should use it. It's important for a number of reasons including but not limited to; the other methods do not work well with arbitrary UI scaling factors (they result in rounding artifacts in UI layout), and they don't work well for localized UIs. If you need to change the layout dynamically you should simply use the autolayout API. @user1756687

Comment: @hukir In that situation you'd want to animate the layout constraint values.

Answer (score 4):

You can add uibbutons programatically in this way:

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(yourMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Jesus Gil y Gil" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 200.0, 60.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to add buttons from code, I'm just curious that why can't I change the position if I create it in IB.

Comment: yes you can change the position, but firt you have to add the reference by the interfaz builder to this button, and then do whatever you want